# How do i create a variable firebase database name?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search a variable data using the Firebase database.

My problem. I'm using an edit text. I want to show the value of the database I wrote here as a text. I only managed to do that. But under the data in my database, there is a data named "name" that works.

-L3131131313
112: 
"ambulans"
name: 
"ambulans"

When I call "112" with Edit Text, it gives me an "ambulance". But I want to do it when there's no database named "name."

This is what should be. The value of "112" should be "ambulance."

-L3131131313
112: 
"ambulans"

The value "112" will be continuously variable. For example, "110", "200", "352", etc. I would like to see the value opposite to the data I'm querying with Edit Text, but I failed. I'd appreciate it if you could help. Sorry for my bad english.

My database photo;
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText Search_Edit_Text;
Button Search_Button;
RecyclerView Search_Contact_List;

DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<CategoryItem> options,options2;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryItem,CategoryViewHolder> adapter;

Query firebaseSearchQuery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("database");

    Search_Edit_Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search_Edit_Text);
    Search_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search_Button);

    Search_Contact_List = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Search_Contact_List);
    Search_Contact_List.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getBaseContext(),2);
    Search_Contact_List.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    Search_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String searchText = Search_Edit_Text.getText().toString();

            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
        }
    });

    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {


    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Started Search", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild(searchText).startAt("").endAt("" + "\uf8ff");

    options2 = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategoryItem>()
            .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,CategoryItem.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryItem, 
    CategoryViewHolder>(options2) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final CategoryItem model) {

        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_layout,parent,false);
            return new CategoryViewHolder(itemView);

        }
    };

    setCategory();
}

private void setCategory() {

    adapter.startListening();
    Search_Contact_List.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My Category Item

```
public class CategoryItem {

public String name;



public CategoryItem() {
}

public CategoryItem(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

I've solved some of my problems. The sample database I will use is as follows. Now I want to do, but I can not produce a solution.

There will be two or more sub-database sets in our database. For example, I will use this database name "+90 505 696 1234" twice. The value of this database is "A" and the value of "AA" in the other set. When I call this phone number with Edit Text, I want it to give me the value "A" and "AA". But I can't make it. Because the CategoryItem class I created is not a variable. I used the name as String value in CategoryItem. I call it with getName (). But if this value is fixed, it works. I cannot find a solution because the user will search for different database names with the help of edit text. I'il be very happy if you can help.

> My Firebase Database

```
{
  "ContactPhoneNumbers" : {
    "-LcaHYcsoGA-VT8yvgGf" : {
      "+90 505 696 1234" : "A",
      "+90 506 854 2345" : "B",
      "+90 530 408 3456" : "C",
      "+90 535 966 4567" : "D",
      "+90 536 782 5678" : "E",
      "+90 546 934 67 89" : "F",
      "+905304080001" : "G",
      "+905316910002" : "H",
      "+905359660003" : "I",
      "+905367820004" : "J",
      "+905425420005" : "K",
      "+905469340006" : "L",
      "05056960007" : "M"
    },
    "-LcaH_gtgarJwbY5-C08" : {
      "+90 505 696 1234" : "AA",
      "+90 506 854 2345" : "BB",
      "+90 530 408 3456" : "CAC",
      "+90 535 966 4567" : "AAA",
      "+90 536 782 5678" : "CAB",
      "+90 546 934 67 89" : "BB",
      "+905304080001" : "A",
      "+905316910002" : "BBB",
      "+905359660003" : "DDD",
      "+905367820004" : "EEE",
      "+905425420005" : "FFF",
      "+905469340006" : "L",
      "05056960007" : "M"
    }
  }
}
```

> My CategoryItem.java

```
public class CategoryItem {

    public String name ;

    public CategoryItem() {

    }

    public CategoryItem(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post a photo of your database structure?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I added. @GastónSaillén

Comment: cant see the photo

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/jgor3W.png @GastónSaillén

Comment: Please check the links before posting them here, I'm getting 403 Forbidden with that link

Comment: You must be related to the service provider of your country. Sorry. https://ibb.co/ww4BJq7  @GastónSaillén

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to tackle the problem you have. But the solution varies depending on the complexity of your dataset.

**Note:** when working with phone numbers, care must be taken to ensure that they are not interpreted as numbers by Firebase and instead kept as strings. For plain phone numbers, adding `"_"` at the start of the number is sufficient. If you wish to distinguish those numbers from those with international caller codes, you can substitute `"_"` for `"+"`.

e.g. "_5417543010" and "+15417543010" are the same US number.

### Solution 1: Two-way map

If you are only matching a number to a string (and vice versa), you can use the following setup:

#### Database structure:

```
{
  "ContactPhoneNumbers": {
    "_110": "fireman",
    "_112": "ambulance",
    "_155": "police",
    "_ambulance": "_112",
    "_fireman": "_110",
    "_police": "_155"
  }
}
```

#### Code:

```
private Query firebaseSearchQueryContacts(String searchText) {
  // will return all entries that start with value of "searchText"
  return mUserDatabase.child("ContactPhoneNumbers").startAt("_" + searchText).endAt("_" + searchText + "\uf8ff");
}
```

#### Problems:

- Phone numbers must be unique. Will not work for cases such as "911" (US) and "000" (AU).
- Must add "_" to the start of every stored key to ensure the search works properly.

### Solution 2: Child objects

For matching a name or phone number to a contact, you can use the following setup:

#### Database structure:

```
{
  "ContactPhoneNumbers": {
    "L213213213232321321": {
      "name": "police",
      "phone": "_155"
    },
    "L312312312": {
      "name": "fireman",
      "phone": "_110"
    },
    "L3131131313": {
      "name": "ambulance",
      "phone": "_112"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Code:

```
private Query firebaseSearchQueryContactsByPhone(String phone) {
  // will return all entries that have a phone number that starts with value of "phone"
  return mUserDatabase.child("ContactPhoneNumbers").orderByChild("phone").startAt("_" + phone).endAt("_" + phone + "\uf8ff");
}

private Query firebaseSearchQueryContactsByName(String name) {
  // will return all entries that have a name that starts with value of "name"
  return mUserDatabase.child("ContactPhoneNumbers").orderByChild("name").startAt(name).endAt(name + "\uf8ff");
}
```

#### Problems:

- Must query phone and name separately.

### Solution 3: Child objects with a lookup index

For matching a name or phone number to a contact, you can use the following setup:

#### Database structure:

```
{
  "ContactPhoneNumbers": {
    "L213213213232321321": {
      "name": "police",
      "phone": "_155"
    },
    "L312312312": {
      "name": "fireman",
      "phone": "_110"
    },
    "L3131131313": {
      "name": "ambulance",
      "phone": "_112"
    }
  },
  "ContactPhoneNumbersIndex"" {
    "_110": "L312312312",
    "_112": "L3131131313",
    "_155": "L213213213232321321",
    "_fireman": "L312312312",
    "_ambulance": "L3131131313",
    "_police": "L213213213232321321"
  }
}
```

#### Code:

```
private Query firebaseSearchQueryContactEntriesByPhone(String phone) {
  // will return all entries that have a phone number that starts with value of "phone"
  return mUserDatabase.child("ContactPhoneNumbers").orderByChild("phone").startAt("_" + phone).endAt("_" + phone + "\uf8ff");
}

private Query firebaseSearchQueryContactEntriesByName(String name) {
  // will return all entries that have a name that starts with value of "name"
  return mUserDatabase.child("ContactPhoneNumbers").orderByChild("name").startAt(name).endAt(name + "\uf8ff");
}

private Query firebaseSearchQueryContactID(String searchText) {
  // will return all IDs that have a phone/name value that starts with value of "searchText"
  return mUserDatabase.child("ContactPhoneNumbersIndex").startAt("_" + searchText).endAt("_" + searchText + "\uf8ff");
}
```

#### Problems:

- Searching by name and number at the same time will return a list of contact IDs rather than contact entries. These must then be read from the server separately.
- Must add "_" to the start of every key stored in the index to ensure the search works properly.
- Index requires being kept in sync with stored contacts. Consider using a Cloud Function for this task.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this explanatory answer and information with me. I shared an update. When you're available, can you please review it and help?

Comment: You should have made the update a separate question. But anyways, I'll check it out after work tomorrow (~15-16 hrs from now).